# How to mark dates in datetime Pick Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetimepicker

I want to mark my days in dateTimePicker on the behalf of bit field from my database in asp.net window forms.Anybody please let me know how to proceed.

thank's In Advance.

Comment: Which days would you like to mark? What is in your database's bit field (i.e. that can only be null, 0 or 1, so how would you like to use this information to mark days)?

Comment: what is this datetimepicker? .NET? Javascript? what have u tried? you can break up this task in two parts, 1: read values (im assuming dates) from your database, and 2: highlight dates in DateTimePicker based on retrieved values.

Comment: Sir I want to mark day in dateTimePicker green if bit value is 1 and red if bit value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `MonthCalendar`control which allows the selection of multiple dates via the `BoldedDates` array:

```
monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = 
    new DateTime[] { DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) };
```

This way you can at least mark your dates differently, although not in different colours but only in normal and **bold**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned ASP.Net, I assume you are using default `Calendar` control. If you see the properties for this control, you will find `SelectedDates` and `SelectedDayStyle`. You can make use of these two to achieve what you are trying.